# Plotly Kaleido Default Width/Height

Tags: python, pyspark, plotly

Good morning everyone !

My first question on Stack Overflow. I use Plotly and as of today I cannot set default width and hight using

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.kaleido.scope.default_width = None
pio.kaleido.scope.default_height = None
```

Has anything changed and does anyone know how to solve this. The following error is displayed

```
Fail to execute line 20: pio.kaleido.scope.default_width = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-706995936990330720.py", line 375, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'default_width'
```

Comment: I ran it with plotly:5.9.0 jupyterlab:3.4.3 and it was configurable with None and no error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, will try to install plotly 5.9.0. Best Strahi

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't have the [`kaleido`](https://pypi.org/project/kaleido/) package installed as it might not be included in plotly by default.

In your python environment do:
`mamba install -c conda-forge python-kaleido`

or:
`pip install kaleido`

to install the package and restart your kernel.